# Story Identification: collection of fantasy stories involving a priest whose world around him accelerates

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As a kid I read a collection of fantasy stories I have only the vaguest memories of. This must have been in the 80s or early 90s.

One story involves a priest who notices that time seems to accelerate around him. It ends with him praying the *pater noster* and taking the whole day for just the first word.

Another story I remember even more vaguely involved a man growing to an unnaturally large size. I don't remember anything about the plot except that the expression *vox populi* somehow played a role.

There were more stories in the collection, but I can't remember any more details.

It is likely that the stories were in German, but they may have been translated from their original language. I don't remember whether all stories were from the same author or not.

Can someone identify the collection, or at least the two stories I mentioned, despite my hazy recollection?

Comment: So, just to be clear, if he took all day for the first word, the world was probably accelerating around the priest, right? Because your title seems to indicate that he is accelerating.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots you are right, of course. Changed title to reflect your observation.

Comment: It's a shame; I liked the accelerating priest better.

Comment: @sqb same. That would be a funny book